# Python: matplotlib - Black and White Scatter

Tags: python, matplotlib

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here, but I can't get a scatter plot in pylab to print in black and white. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated. Here's my code:

```
from pylab import *
from random import random
ioff()

r = range(10)
x = [3 + i + random() for i in r]
y = [50*i + random() for i in r]
x2 = [5 + i + random() for i in r]
y2 = [5*i + random() for i in r]

scatter(x,y, marker = 'o', hold = True, label = 'collected underwear',cmap=cm.Greys)
scatter(x2,y2, marker = 's', hold = True, label = 'Profit!',cmap=cm.Greys)
legend(loc='upper left')

show()
```

Thanks,

Adam

Comment: You mean you want the markers black?

Comment: Thanks @deinonychusaur; yes, that's what I'm looking for, or a gray-scale if that's possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you simply want to specify the color arbitrarily, do

```
color="k"
```

for black, and do

```
color="0.x"
```

for greyscale, `x` could be any number as long as 0.x is between 0 and 1.

But if you want the marker color be determined by another array `z`, do

```
scatter(x,y,c=z, cmap=cm.Greys)
```

so for

```
from pylab import *
from random import random
r = range(10)
x = [3 + i + random() for i in r]
y = [50*i + random() for i in r]
x2 = [5 + i + random() for i in r]
y2 = [5*i + random() for i in r]
z2 = [i + random() for i in r]
scatter(x,y,   c="0.1", marker = 'o', hold = True, label = 'collected underwear')
scatter(x2,y2, c=z2,marker = 's',  hold = True, label = 'Profit!',cmap=cm.Greys)
legend(loc='upper left')
show()
```

you will have

[image]

Comment: nice examples, but the legend colour doesn't match the markers on Profit!

Comment: I wanted to put a `color="0.5"` in the second scatter statement, but worried that it would confuse the OP, so I strip it off and leave the legend as is. You can definite add that back for better illustration (I just did).

Comment: @Adam_G u r welcome! remember to put `color="0.5"` back to the second scatter statement to avoid blue points in the legend.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want the curves to be black, just add:

```
color='k'
```

to each scatter line and they will be black. No need for cmap.

**Edit:**

If you want greyscale you can always use colortuples instead:

```
color = (0.1,0.1,0.1,1) #(r,g,b,a)
```

I don't know if you can use cm:s directly.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to do a gray scale?

Comment: Yes, I edited the answer for one way of setting greyscale values.